# Collapsed PanoramaItem briefly appears when swiping

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

I have a weird experience when using a panorama control on 7.1... I'm trying to toggle the visibility of a PanoramaItem programmatically. But while it works fine and the PanoramaItem toggles (i.e. PanItemA is hidden, while PanItemB is shown) , the hidden PanoramaItem reappears briefly while swiping right (from first item to last).

I have no clue how to solve it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that it has something to do with bitmap caching when swiping occurs? Can I force caching?

Answer (score 2):

It's not good idea show/hide Items for Panorama. 
Try remove/add them instead.

Comment: Here's a "Panorama control best practices" article in MSDN where hiding/showing is mentioned as a perfectly valid option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941107(v=VS.92).aspx . Besides, even when I show/hide content within a PanoramaItem, the same effect occurs.